# Working with XamDataGrid and trying to get a special value out of a sender object from the RecordActivated() function

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, infragistics

**Hello there**,

i'm a stuck with a problem, i can't figure out a solution to.
Since i don't have a lot of experience with infragistics and wpf i created a test-project first to try how to do it properly.

I got a xamComboEditor which contains a comboBox.
When i open the comboBox i got a xamDataGrid with a "states"-table in it. 
After selecting one row, i need to write the primary key of the selected row into the comboBox.
My problem here is that i got the the sender object, when the RecordActivated()-Event triggers but i don't know how to read the data i need from it.
When i look at the sender object with the VisualStudio watchlist-tool i can find the data i need but i've no idea how to get the value of it.

I need to get the "row" value inside of the sender-object which is already pretty hidden to find with the watchlist-tool. 
After searching for a while i found the right values. 
I found it there:
sender -> ActiveRecord -> dataItem -> row

Test.xaml.cs:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class test : Window
    {
       public test()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           runFASTWMVDataSetTableAdapters.StaatenTableAdapter staat = new runFASTWMVDataSetTableAdapters.StaatenTableAdapter();
           combo.ItemsSource = staat.GetData().DefaultView;          
       }
       //MainGrid2 is the grid which is in my combobox 
       private void MainGrid2_RecordActivated(object sender, Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.Events.RecordActivatedEventArgs e)
       {
            //combo is my comboBox object
            combo.IsDropDownOpen = false;   
           //guess i need to somehow read the "row" from the sender object right here. 
       }
    }
 }
```

I'll just post the parts of the xaml which is really important since i got a pretty long xaml.

test.xaml:

```
 <igWPF:XamComboEditor x:Name="combo" Margin="1,1,1,219" ComboBoxStyle="{DynamicResource ComboStyle}" 
 DisplayValueSource="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">  
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
         <igWPF:XamDataGrid x:Name="MainGrid2"  DataSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}"   
         RecordActivated="MainGrid2_RecordActivated" GroupByAreaLocation="None" SelectedDataItemsScope="RecordsOnly"/>  
    </Grid>
 </igWPF:XamComboEditor>
```

After struggling and googling a few hours I haven't got any idea left to try, so i thought i may ask you guys for your help. 
Hopefully i didn't deleted anything while formating the code for the post it does work like intended on my local project.
Also sorry if i got some grammar errors in my post, english isn't my first language.

Comment: Well after a while of trying to find a solution to the problem, our boss decided to start using DevExpress instead of Infragistics, because it works better in most of the cases we had and had a solution for our problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since you asked your question, but I would like to answer your question, even if you do not use the grid anymore. Perhaps this answer will help others.

---

I created an example, which will show you:

1. How to get a special value out of a sender object?
2. How you could bind the ActiveRecord of your XamDataGrid to the SelectedItem of the XamComboEditor
3. Another approach of a ComboBox within a nested kind of a DataGrid.

---

My example contains the following classes:

**`Person.cs`**

```
namespace XamDataGridDemo
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{LastName}, {FirstName} ({Age})";
        }
    }
}
```

**`MainWindow.xaml`**

```
<Window x:Class="XamDataGridDemo.MainWindow"
        x:Name="Demo"

        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

        xmlns:ig="http://schemas.infragistics.com/xaml"
        xmlns:dp="http://infragistics.com/DataPresenter"
        xmlns:editors="http://infragistics.com/Editors"

        Title="XamDataGridDemo" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Demo}"
        >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Reference InfragisticsWPF4.v16.1.dll -->
        <!-- Reference InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v16.1.dll -->
        <dp:XamDataGrid x:Name="FirstPersonGrid" 
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        DataSource="{Binding Path=Persons}"
                        RecordActivated="PersonGrid_OnRecordActivated"
                        />

        <Separator Grid.Row="1" Margin="3" />

        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!-- Reference InfragisticsWPF4.Editors.v16.1.dll -->
            <editors:XamComboEditor x:Name="Combo"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Persons}"
                                    SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=SecondPersonGrid, Path=ActiveDataItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                    />

            <!-- Reference InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v16.1.dll -->
            <dp:XamDataGrid x:Name="SecondPersonGrid" 
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            DataSource="{Binding Path=Persons}"
                            />
        </Grid>

        <Separator Grid.Row="3" Margin="3" />

        <!-- Reference InfragisticsWPF4.Controls.Editors.XamComboEditor.v16.1.dll -->
        <ig:XamMultiColumnComboEditor Grid.Row="4"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Persons}"
                                      EmptyText="Select a Person ..."
                                      SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Id, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                      SelectionChanged="XamMultiColumnComboEditor_OnSelectionChanged"
                                      />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**`MainWindow.xaml.cs`**

```
namespace XamDataGridDemo
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Windows;

    using Infragistics.Controls.Editors;
    using Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter;
    using Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.Events;

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.Persons = new List<Person>
                               {
                                   new Person { Id = 0, FirstName = "Horst", LastName = "Horstenson", Age = 55 },
                                   new Person { Id = 1, FirstName = "Hilde", LastName = "Wild", Age = 45 },
                                   new Person { Id = 2, FirstName = "Klaus", LastName = "Klausen", Age = 50 }
                               };

            DataContext = this.Persons;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public IList<Person> Persons { get; }

        private void PersonGrid_OnRecordActivated(object sender, RecordActivatedEventArgs e)
        {
            var xamDataGrid = (XamDataGrid)sender;
            var activePerson = xamDataGrid.ActiveDataItem as Person;
            if (activePerson != null)
            {
                // if you want to do something with the properties
                int id = activePerson.Id;
                string firstName = activePerson.FirstName;
                string lastName = activePerson.LastName;
                int age = activePerson.Age;

                MessageBox.Show($"You have selected {activePerson}", "Selected Person");
            }

            // Second Approch -- Your Watchlist
            var record = xamDataGrid.ActiveRecord as DataRecord;
            activePerson = record?.DataItem as Person;
            if (activePerson != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"You have selected {activePerson}", "Selected Person");
            }
        }

        private void XamMultiColumnComboEditor_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var xamMultiColumnComboEditor = (XamMultiColumnComboEditor)sender;
            var activePerson = xamMultiColumnComboEditor.SelectedItem as Person;

            if (activePerson == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            MessageBox.Show($"You have selected {activePerson}", "Selected Person");

            // Have to add reference to InfragisticsWPF4.DataManager.v16.1.dll
            if (xamMultiColumnComboEditor.SelectedValue is int)
            {
                int id = (int)xamMultiColumnComboEditor.SelectedValue;

                MessageBox.Show($"You have selected the person with id: {id}", "Selected Value");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**1. How to get a special value out of a sender object?**

As you can see in `void PersonGrid_OnRecordActivated(object sender, RecordActivatedEventArgs e)` I assume that the sender is a `XamDataGrid` and I check if the `ActiveDataItem` is an object of my type `Person`.
Or if you want following your watchlist approach. You could use the casted `sender` and check if the `ActiveRecord` is a `DataRecord` of my type `Person`.

And now you can do anything you want with your "row" object.

**2. How you could bind the ActiveRecord of your XamDataGrid to the SelectedItem of the XamComboEditor?**

I'm a little bit lazy so I shorten the thing the second example a bit and using `XamDataGrid` outside of the `XamComboEditor`, but it should work also within a nested grid, because I use a Binding with ElementName.

So as you can see I just bound the SelectenItem of the `XamComboEditor` to the `ActiveDataItem` of the `XamDataGrid`.

```
SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=SecondPersonGrid, Path=ActiveDataItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

I used also `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to set the `ActiveDataItem` to the `SelectedItem`.

**3. Another approach of a ComboBox within a nested kind of a DataGrid.**

As you already tried [infragistics](/questions/tagged/infragistics) you should take a look at the `XamMultiColumnComboEditor` which is, as the name says, a combobox with columns you could define. 
You can use the same approach as in 1. to get the selected `Person` from the sender. See `void XamMultiColumnComboEditor_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)` from the code above. 
To fit your needs, to get the "row-id" I bound the SelectedValue to the `Id` property of the selected `Person`.

```
SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Id, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

---

I used **Infragistics v16.1** and had to add the following reference to my project.

- InfragisticsWPF4.Controls.Editors.XamComboEditor.v16.1.dll
- InfragisticsWPF4.DataManager.v16.1.dll
- InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v16.1.dll
- InfragisticsWPF4.Editors.v16.1.dll
- InfragisticsWPF4.Editors.v16.1.dll

---

*If something is unclear or to broad, feel free to ask for clarification.*

Comment: Totally forget that question. 

At the point you answered the question, i already started with new projects but thanks anyway for the solution you offered.